# Nix: nixlang syntax how to change an existing set ? Syntax error unexpected '=' , expecting $end

Tags: nix

```
nix repl
nix-repl> test = {"a"=10;}
nix-repl> test.a
nix-repl> 10
nix-repl> test.a=20
error: syntax error, unexpected '=' , expecting $end, at (string):1:7
```

Expected result:

```
test = {"a"=20;}
```

I am currently learning nix and couldn't find the answer after a few minutes of google.
This seems rather simple and I'm sure someone instantly knows this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in `nix` are immutable; you can't change the value of `test.a`, because that would require changing the set. You can only create a *new* set with a different `a` value.

```
nix-repl> test = {"a"=10;}

nix-repl> test // {"a"=20;}
{ a = 20; }

nix-repl> test
{ a = 10; }

nix-repl> test2 = test // {"a"=20;}

nix-repl> test2
{ a = 20; }
```

The `//` operator combines two sets, with values on the right-hand side overriding values on the left.

```
nix-repl> {"a"=10; "b"=20;} // {"a"="changed"; c="30";}
{ a = "changed"; b = 20; c = "30"; }
```

Comment: Note that you can bind ("assign to") a variable in the repl multiple times, but that only affects the meaning of that name in expressions you enter afterwards.